# Program Stuck on Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I open a program, and then open another program, I can't restore the first program that minimized. The program is stuck on the taskbar. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> doesn't work, but <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> does.

[image]

The program(s) I want to open are just blinking.

How can I fix this? I have tried to right-click taskbar -> cascade windows, but this is waste a time.

I'm using Windows 7 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when your computer is very slow. Whenever I run multiple programs, Windows does this too. It's because you're telling the program to open, but it's taking too long to open. Thus, it says it has something to tell you (such as a Skype chat notification, setup finish, etc. basically whenever the icon is yellow), and it's not starting yet. The solution is to make sure your computer is fast enough to run all of these programs.

Comment: My laptop is 1.4Ghz 4GB RAM. In the screenshot i only open few program that using little memory except chrome. Is there another reason ? if not i will make this as answer.

Comment: From personal experience this is the only reason I had this happen. You can also run `sfc /scannow` from the command prompt (run as admin) and see if there are any file system errors.